# generate a dictionary from a dictionary python -for if

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Hi I have this dictionary:

```
miembros = {
    1: {"nombre": "Farly Waller", "`pais": "Russia", "siguiendo": [2, 3]},
    2: {"nombre": "Jania Hardistry", "pais": "Indonesia", "siguiendo": [1, 3]}, 
    3: {"nombre": "Yale Shortan", "pais": "Brazil", "siguiendo": [1, 2]}, 
    4: {"nombre": "kevin", "pais": "portugal", "siguiendo": []}
}
```

i am going to generate a dictionary, assigned to the followers variable, with the list of followers grouped by user identifier

**Examples**:

- For user `1`, the value should be the list `[2,3]`.
- For user `4`, the value should be the empty list (`[]`).

I try this:

```
seguidores = {}
for i in miembros:
 seguidores[i] = seguidores.get(i, 0)
```

Comment: `{k: v['siguiendo'] for k, v in miembros.items()}`?

Answer (score 0):

When you loop dict it return key, value pair. So you should make something like this.
`for key, value in members.items(): new_dict[key] = value["siguiendo"]`